# templates in one directive depending on conditon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How is it possible to replace a div tag in the directive?

For instance I have a panel with a div-tag:

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="whatever">
            This tag has to be replaced in the directive after the counter is 10! 
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i have a template **change-Div.html**

```
<div class="whatever2">
   I am the new div-Tag!
</div>
```

Is this possible? If yes how? The ng-show would be also a alternative, but not a nice one. I want to define many templates for this tag. depending on the condition (variable) the template should be loaded. 
In the directive you can load a template, but how can I decide which template should be loaded?

For instance if checked= true load template 1- if checked is false laod template 2

thx in advance

I am using an eyetracker and have many panels. And with the eye positions I check in the directive where user is looking. So which panel is on focus:

```
myApp.directive('travelInformation', function ($rootScope, $interval) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        updateMethod: '=',
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var routePanelCounter = 0;
        var timeTablePanelCounter = 0;
        var count = 10;

        this.routePanelUpdate = function (element) {
            routePanelCounter +=1
            if (routePanelCounter == count) {
                //replace the old tag with the new template1

            }
        };

        this.timeTablePanelUpdate = function (element) {
            timeTablePanelCounter += 1;
            if (timeTablePanelCounter == count) {
                //replace the old tag with the new template2
            }

        };


        $interval(function () {
            var boundingRect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            if ($rootScope.gazePoints){
                for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.gazePoints.length; i++) {
                    var x = $rootScope.gazePoints[i].x;
                    var y = $rootScope.gazePoints[i].y;

                    if (x >= boundingRect.left && x <= boundingRect.right && y >= boundingRect.top && y <= boundingRect.bottom) {
                        console.log("Has Focus");
                        this[scope.updateMethod](element);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
};
```

});

And the html looks following:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary fixed-panel" travel-information data-update-method="'routePanelUpdate'">
<div class="panel-heading">test1</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    old content /// replace the the div-tag with a new template
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary fixed-panel" travel-information data-update-method="'timeTablePanelUpdate'">
<div class="panel-heading">test2</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div>
        Old content 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the first panel is on focus than the routePanelUpdate methods is called. And here I want to load an template. I do not want to make if-tags in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

U could use ng-bind-html="yourVariable" on parent div and change yourVariable in contoller
And mbe u will need to use $sce.trustAsHtml(yourVariable) after changing value
and include '$sce' as dependency of controller

Answer (score 0):

You can just include templates when needed with the `ng-include` directive in combination with `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-if="fish ==='salmon'" ng-include="'whatever.html'"></div>
<div ng-if="fish ==='perch'" ng-include="'whatever2.html'"></div>
```

Comment: but this should happen in the directive. How can I do this?

Comment: You simply have this markup inside the template for the directive. Be sure to organize your files and folders well whe doing this so that you can maintain the app easier.

Comment: I edit my code to explain what i actually want. pls check above

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got the solution on my own.

I use $templateRequest and than convert the html to an actual DOM node. Before this I clear the old data with empty():

```
this.routePanelUpdate = function (element) {
                routePanelCounter += 1
                if(routePanelCounter == 10){
                    element.empty();
                    $templateRequest(templateURL).then(function (html) {
                        var template = angular.element(html);
                        element.append(template);

                    });
                }
            };
```

If somebody have a better solution so pls tell me.